# Replacing the URL on a local page

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

So I am building a page for a school work and I want to change the URL to match whatever.

`http://localhost/meet/myprofile.php`

I want to change it to

```
http://localhost/meet/(username here)
```

or

```
http://localhost/meet/login
```

I want the user changed to whatever is written in the database, but for example let's say `$_SESSION['username']`

I was searching earlier by I can't get it done.

Comment: We are running on XAMPP, so I suppose it should support .htaccess? @Starkeen

Comment: I was trying to use [this](https://moz.com/blog/create-crawlable-link-friendly-ajax-websites-using-pushstate) but I couldn't get it to wrok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that you can use session but can cookie with the code below in htaccess. Suppose, yuo already set cookie username as Tommy

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} username=(\w+)
RewriteRule meet/myprofile.php /meet/%1
```

then `/meet/myprofile.php` will be redirected to `/meet/Tommy`

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend use .htaacces rewrite rule. The Basic idea is, that it takes given url and internally maps php file on it. It supports $_GET requests therefore you can create URL like

```
http://webpage.com/article/85/
```

that will be translated with . htaccess like this

```
http://webpage.com/article.php?id=85
```

Using rule like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^article/$1/$ article.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Here is really nice tutorial how it works. Hope you manage to solve it, if not, feel free to comment and ask. ;)

https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: if I wanted to write $_SESSION['user'] in the .htaccess do I have to write anything special like php tags or ?

Comment: In .htaacces as it's mostly only set of rules I don't think using PHP is possible. But as @splash58 said, you might try with cookie. ;)